# Conditional Operator with and without ()

Tags: java, conditional-operator, operator-precedence

I have run in to some weird thing when I want to print one of my objects (which is obviously not null).

If I use this line:

```
text.append("\n [ITEM ID]: " + (item == null ? (otherItem == null ? 0 : otherItem .getItems().get(i).getId()) : item .getItems().get(i).getId()));
```

There is no null pointer exception if my `item` object is `null`. Of course this should be the excepted result. But if I use it without the `()` marks:

```
text.append("\n [ITEM ID]: " + item == null ? (otherItem == null ? 0 : otherItem .getItems().get(i).getId()) : item .getItems().get(i).getId())
```

I thought the conditional operator does not execute the other part of the operator, but I got a NullPointerException.

I would appreciate if someone explain it to me, why it is essential to use the `()` marks in this case.

Comment: A case of operator precedence?

Comment: Hint: `"\n [ITEM ID]: " + item` becomes...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenation between `"\n [ITEM ID]: "` and `item`  will have priority on the equality test and the conditional operator if you don't put the parenthesis (see the [precedences](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php) in Java operators), so you have to put them if you want it to work (as `("\n [ITEM ID]: " + item) == null` is probably not what you want to evaluate).

Comment: Thanks. Two perfect answer, i dunno which one accept. But i think i should accept the first one, but thank you very much talnicolas! Thats what i needed parenthesis...

Comment: @czupe Well I actually answered first, but you're welcome anyway ;)

Comment: ok. If your were the first, and evaluating that you wrote the == vs + operators, i think you earn my acceptence. Thanks again. Have a nice day...

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator has higher precedence than `? :`, so you do need to use parenthesis. See http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php

Comment: Higher precedence than `==`, in this case.

Comment: yeah more preciously the concatenation operator has higher precedence than == ( and the conditional operator is irrelevant), i understand it....